# Optimize Partitionning for billions of distinct keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm processing a file each day with PySpark for contaning information about device navigation through the web. At the end of each month I want to use window functions in order to have the navigation journey for each device. It's a very slow processing, even with many nodes, so I'm looking for ways to speed it up.

My idea was to partition the data but I have 2 billion distinct keys, so `partitionBy` does not seem appropriate. Even `bucketBy` might not be a good choice because I create `n` buckets each day, so the files are not appended but for each day there are x parts of files that are created.

Does anyone have a solution ?

So here is an example of the export for each day (inside of each parquet file we find 9 partitions):

[image]

And here is the partitionBy query that we launch at the beggining of each month (compute_visit_number and compute_session_number are two udf that i've created on the notebook):
[image]

Comment: Could you add some sample data and the code that you tried and that needs to be optimized? It would help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've added more screenshot and examples

Answer (score 0):

You want to ensure that each devices data is in the same partition to prevent exchanges when you do your window function. Or at least minimise the number of partitions the data could be in.

To do this I would create a column called partitionKey when you write the data - which contained a mod on the mc_device column - where the number you mod by is the number of partitions you want. Base this number of the size of the cluster that will run the end of month query. (If mc_device is not an integer then create a checksum first).

You can create a secondary partition on the date column if still needed.

Your end of month query should change:

```
w = Windows.partitionBy('partitionKey', 'mc_device').orderBy(event_time')
```

If you kept the date as a secondary partition column then repartition the dataframe to partitionKey only:

```
df = df.repartition('partitionKey')
```

At this point each devices data will be in the same partition and no exchanges should be needed. The sort should be faster and your query will hopefully complete in a sensible time.

If it is still slow you need more partitions when writing the data.